# Chat messaging application for ios

Tags: ios, networking

I am using simple peer-to-peer chat room iPhone app which makes use of local wifi network: https://bitbucket.org/snej/chatty/src. I would like to be able to use an internet-based connection instead of the local wifi network. 
Alternatively I have tried to create a socket based iPhone App and Server: http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server. The simple tcp server works, i have tested it and i get the response but the client doesn't. What went wrong?

Could you please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not enough information over your situation. Due to lack of specific questions it will be really complicated to do research and provide answers or ideas for your case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup some server to achieve that.

```
iPhone<----->wifi router (local IP address range!)<----->internet<------>[something here!]
```

[something here!] will not be able to send packages to your iPhone, because it's local wifi address is not routed in internet. You would need to do some port forwarding magic to get this running, but this is odd since you would need to require all users to be changing their router's config and so on.

Using the mobile network

```
iPhone<----->mobile network operator<----->internet<------>[something here!]
```

does not improve that situation, because MNOs tend to filter their incoming trafic (at least in Europe) - 
you just can not ping/ftp/ssh/connect to the phones on their networks.
That's why there is Apple Push Notification service and so on...

The correct setup is to make both phones clients and talk to a server 
doing the session handling for both of them.

```
iPhone<----->wifi router (local IP address range!)<----->internet<------> YOUR 
                                                                          SERVER 
iPhone<----->mobile network operator<------------------->internet<------> HERE!
```